# SHA1 hashes not matching between my Rails and Cocoa apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, objective-c, ruby, cocoa, sha1

I have a Cocoa app send some data along with a SHA1 hash of that data to a Rails app which verifies that the data and the hash match, but they do not.

To be sure I have logged hex versions of the data that is hashed to the console at both the Rails and Cocoa sides, and they match exactly.

Here's the Cocoa part:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

//...

- (NSData *)dataOfSHA1Hash
{
    unsigned char hashBytes[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA1([self bytes], CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH, hashBytes);

    return [NSData dataWithBytes:hashBytes length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
}

//...

NSData *signatureData = [signedData dataOfSHA1Hash];
NSString *signature = [signatureData hexadecimalString];
```

..and Rails:

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(signed_data)
```

Note that -hexadecimalString is a custom extension to NSData (didn't seem to be built in), which I've tested. That method does not seem to be the problem.

So, why don't my SHA1 hashes match on the same data? Any ideas?

**Edit: example**

For the string "Hello World!"

```
Cocoa: f98ee9c814c2f3c66ccdca641298d12cd26741ec
Rails: 2ef7bde608ce5404e97d5f042f95f89f1c232871
```

Cocoa:

```
NSMutableData *signedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[signedData appendData:[@"Hello World!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *signatureData = [signedData dataOfSHA1Hash];
[signedData release];
NSString *signature = [signatureData hexadecimalString];

NSLog(@"Signature: %@", signature);
// output: Signature: f98ee9c814c2f3c66ccdca641298d12cd26741ec
```

Ruby:

```
>> Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Hello World!")
=> "2ef7bde608ce5404e97d5f042f95f89f1c232871"
```

Comment: could you post a sample datum and digests so we can see which is incorrect?

Comment: FWIW - I just discovered this same problem in my iPhone app.  CC_SHA1 was not returning the same hashes as the Python hashlib.sha1 stuff does.  I did not have the same incorrect-length-passing issue as sjmulder did either, which was proved by the fact that simply changing to use the OpenSSL SHA1() implementation instead of CC_SHA1() actually fixed it.  Didn't change arguments or anything, just which function I called to compute the hash.  Very strange and worrying that CC_SHA1() appears to be buggy.

Comment: I had a similar bug, however in my case I was using the data pointer itself for the first argument to `CC_SHA1`.  I should have been using `[data bytes]`.  It took an embarrassingly long time to figure this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the error, stupid little thing:

```
-CC_SHA1([self bytes], CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH, hashBytes);
+CC_SHA1([self bytes], [self length], hashBytes);
```

I sent the length of the digest instead of the length of the data. Don't know how I could've made such a mistake – and then overlook it for hours.