# NSData to NSString after CC_SHA1

Tags: cocoa-touch, hash

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690246/sha1-hashes-not-matching-between-my-rails-and-cocoa-apps) I wrote a category on `NSString` to `hash NSString` instances using SHA1. However, there is something wrong with my implementation. The funny thing is that logging the NSData instance does give the expected hash, but when I want to create an NSString from that NSData instance, I simply get null.

```
- (NSString *)sha1 {
    NSData *dataFromString = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char hashed[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if ( CC_SHA1([dataFromString bytes], [dataFromString length], hashed) ) {
        NSData *dataFromDigest = [NSData dataWithBytes:hashed length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[dataFromDigest bytes] length:[dataFromDigest length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        return result;

    } else {

        return nil;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of a hash function is just a bare bunch of bytes. You're taking those bytes, and essentially telling NSString that they represent a UTF8-encoded string, which they don't. The resulting NSString is just garbage.

It sounds like what you really want is something like a string of hexadecimal digits that represent the hash value? If so, I believe you'll need to roll this yourself by looping through the `dataFromDigest` one byte at a time and outputting into a new NSMutableString the right hex digits depending on the byte's value. You can do it yourself or use some code from the web. [The comment on this post](http://notes.stripsapp.com/nsdata-to-nsstring-as-hex-bytes/) looks promising.

Comment: Thanks quixoto. This clarifies a lot!